# Несколько картинок в html

Tags: html

Как сделать, чтобы в html была не одна картинка, а две, три?

Comment: Отредактируйте картинку, сделав коллаж.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одну смог добавить? Таким же образом и другие...

```
<img src="путь к файлу_1"/> // одна картинка

<img src="путь к файлу_2"/> // две картинки

<img src="путь к файлу_3"/> // три картинки
```

Comment: чтобы картинки менялись а сайт оставался прежним

Comment: Встань на место читателя и прочти свои впросы! Ну как? Все понял?

Comment: да все понял.

Comment: Нет, все таки думаю не понял, я имел ввиду, что твои вопросы ОЧЕНЬ не конкретны и догадываться ни кому не хочется, описывай более подробно свои цели, и то чего хочешь добиться в результате, так будет проще...

Comment: Согласен)) Не вопрос а бред....